# SFML Thread does not works for window

Tags: multithreading, sfml

I have simple code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

sf::RenderWindow *mainWindow;

void changeMainWindowParameters()
{
    while(mainWindow->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mainWindow->pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mainWindow->close();
                return;
            }
        }
        mainWindow->clear();
        mainWindow->draw(sf::CircleShape(50.0F, 30));
        mainWindow->display();
    }
}
int main()
{
    mainWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(
            sf::VideoMode(100, 100), "Window");
    changeMainWindowParameters();

}
```

But if I want to do it with threads, it does not work as in previous example:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

sf::RenderWindow *mainWindow;

void changeMainWindowParameters()
{
    while(mainWindow->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mainWindow->pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mainWindow->close();
                return;
            }
        }
        mainWindow->clear();
        mainWindow->draw(sf::CircleShape(50.0F, 30));
        mainWindow->display();
    }
}
int main()
{
    mainWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(
            sf::VideoMode(100, 100), "Window");
    sf::Thread th(changeMainWindowParameters);
    th.launch();
    //code
    th.wait();

}
```

I can't close the window/move it etc.

I want the program to do something (drawing images on this window etc.) and so I could close/move this window.

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

sf::RenderWindow *mainWindow = nullptr;

void changeMainWindowParameters()
{
    if (mainWindow == nullptr)
        mainWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(100, 100), "Window");
    while(mainWindow->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mainWindow->pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mainWindow->close();
                return;
            }
        }
        mainWindow->clear();
        mainWindow->draw(sf::CircleShape(50.0F, 30));
        mainWindow->display();
    }
}
int main()
{
    sf::Thread th(changeMainWindowParameters);

    th.launch();
    for(;;)
        std::cout << '.';
    th.wait();

}
```

We must remember that the event loop (more precisely, the pollEvent or waitEvent function) must be called in the same thread that created the window.